Help me find this late 80s-early 90s psychic alien movie
Regular guy gets drafted to help "save the planet"
by a female alien who looks human and has British accent.
She is psychic and knows what he is thinking,
which leads to several uncomfortable situations
when he looks at her.
Their biology is MUCH different, has to do with light? (as seen in water).
She is trying to find something... some energy source maybe.
Some other alien I think wants to use it as a weapon.
I think it was on Showtime, but could not swear to it.
I might have seen it on iTunes a few years ago when looking for something else,
but was not there when I went looking for it later to confirm it was the same.

It sounds like you're looking for the 1988 miniseries Something Is Out There.

Two police officers investigate a series of brutal murders in which the victims have had bodily organs removed. When one of them questions a young woman who has been seen at the crime scenes, it turns out she is an alien from an interstellar prison ship and that the murders have been committed by a powerful xenomorphic alien which had escaped. 

British actress Maryam d'Abo plays the alien woman who can read minds, which becomes awkward because the hero is attracted to her. This miniseries actually came up many times in ID here before, but the questions are quite different. It was later developed into a series that didn't do well and was quickly cancelled. Here's the promo:




See also the approved answers here, here and here and a non-approved one here.

Thank you!    Will adding the other questions in the comments make them find-able here in a search as well? Consolidating all questions to one answer, to make future IDs easier?

I have no idea, sorry. I contemplated marking this as a duplicate but eventually decided against it. BTW, it came up yet another time here, but I ran out of room in the previous comment (it was about to exceed the character limit). Glad you found it, anyway. :)
